# Not able to upgrade OpenSSL version from 1.1.1g to 1.1.1l in RHEL 8.4

Tags: linux, redhat, openssl, rhel8, cve

I have Linux machine RHEL 8.4 with OpenSSL 1.1.1g. After running the vulnerability and penetration testing, It was found that this version of OpenSSL is not secured and recommended to upgrade OpenSSL 1.1.1g --> 1.1.1l

When I'm giving the command:

`sudo yum update openssl`

It's showing that version is already up to date.

1.Is this the correct way to update the version?
2.Is it like RHEL 8 has backported fixes of  1.1.1l  in the base version 1.1.1g?

Comment: `Is it like RHEL 8 has backported fixes` - Probably, find the source and check the change logs.